# Chrome Hosted App and chrome.notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I'm trying to get an authoritative answer on the following:
Can a [Chrome hosted app](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions#3types) use the [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications.html) API?

Mind - I know it can use [HTML5 Desktop Notifications](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/html5desktopalerts/). But, I'm unsure about chrome.notifications.

When running the notifications [example app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/rich-notifications) packaged as an extension - it works. However, the same code, when packaged as an hosted app fails on recognizing the notifications object.

So, can a [Chrome hosted app](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions#3types) use the [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications.html) API?